# How to build lighter version of opencv_java3 for android?

Tags: android, opencv

I'm following [these lines](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/platforms/android/android.toolchain.cmake#L36-L40) to build OpenCV's libraries for Android.

```
Usage Linux:
$ export ANDROID_NDK=/absolute/path/to/the/android-ndk
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=path/to/the/android.toolchain.cmake ..
$ make -j8
```

The built `libopencv_java3.so` file **for one architecture** (`armeabi-v7a`) is **8.3MB** large.

Is there a way to omit some unused modules on build to get lighter libraries ?

Comment: Hi, I cannot build it with the java3.so file, can you please show your full cmake command? Thanks

Comment: @InfinityChaos everything is in the code above. Maybe you forgot the last two points of the cmake command

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked

Comment: For your question, have you tried building OpenCV with only the libraries you need? Command line gets messy for OpenCV as it has too many options to select. Have you tried using CMake-GUI? It keeps those options arranged.

Comment: Yes, I've tried this. but I should not disable modules to get the same size as the distributed library.

Comment: I followed the same procedure but I am not seeing a single (libopencv_java3.so) file, there was individual .a  files, could any one let us know how to build opencv_java3.so